# What is tag-only forced cache inclusion called?

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture

Is there a commonly accepted term for caches that are guaranteed inclusive with respect to tags but not data?

Inclusion can be helpful to simplify cache coherence, for which use only tags need to be included (avoiding the overhead of storing additional data). Is there a commonly accepted term for this kind of inclusion to distinguish it from inclusion that also replicates data?

I have used "tag-inclusive", but a professional (Mitch Alsup on the comp.arch Usenet newsgroup) used "virtually inclusive". (The former is more physically descriptive, but the latter has some conceptual attractiveness and might fit with the use of an approximate but conservative filter.)